# Is every bijection that preserves element order an isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

I know the converse is true, and I suspect the statement is not true, but I can't think of counter example.

Comment: An isomorphism of *what*? Which order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No: take a cyclic group $G$ of prime order $p$. Then all the elements but $0$ have the same order $p$, but it should be clear that you can set up a bijection from $G$ to itself that doesn't do the composition correctly: take $p=5$, for example, and set
$$ f(0)=0, \quad f(1)=1, \quad f(2)=3, \quad \&c. $$
Then $f(1)+f(1)=2 \neq 3= f(2)=f(1+1)$, for example.

Comment: Congratulations for understanding what the OP meant. I was still scratching my head.

Comment: Thankfully I thought to look at the tag :)

Comment: Ok, so the map here would not be an isomorphism, but the groups would be isomorphic. Is there a situation where we have a bijection that preserves order between two non isomorphic groups?

Comment: I looked at the tag too, and was like Matt still scratching my head.

Comment: @H_B There is an order preserving bijection between an elementary abelian 27-group and a non-abelian group of order 27.

Comment: Chappers must be a really good teacher. Sometimes I ask nonsensical questions and the professor doesn't understand me, but I know a friend who is really good at teaching and understands what I mean even when I ask poorly worded questions

Comment: I am suspecting that because you were able to answer that last question so fast, that the answer is not so obvious. Can you think of a easier example? Or is this known to be the smallest such example?

I am sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: @h_b you're right that it's one of those things that's sort of sitting around for ready recall, but the other answer has another example that's smaller and more familiar.

Comment: That was the smallest example I could come up with: the groups of lower orders are the trivial group, the group of order $2$ (each with only one order-preserving bijection), the group of order $3$ (two bijections, but one's trivial and the other takes each element to its inverse, so no counterexample there). The annoying case is $4$, but it's again clear that there are only two order-preserving bijections on the cyclic group. That leaves the Klein 4-group, but everything has order $2$ there, and hence you can show there's only 3 bijections there, none of which are incompatible.

Comment: @Chappers:  well, $3!$ order-preserving bijections for the Klein 4-group.  But yes, they are all automorphisms.  So $\mathbb Z/5$ is the smallest counterexample.  Note that in fact every group with an element $g$ of order $> 4$ produces a counterexample:  switch $g^2$ with $g^{-2}$ without changing anything else.

Comment: It may even be true that only finitely many finite groups $G$ have the property that all order-preserving bijections $G \to G$ are automorphisms.

Comment: ... in fact, I claim you've already found all such groups!  By Groups's answer below, any such group must be abelian, and by my observation two comments up, it must be either a product of cyclic factors of orders 2 and 4, or an elementary abelian 3-group.  In the latter case, we can easily find non-automorphisms if it's bigger than just $\mathbb Z/3$.  In the former case, we can similarly find non-automorphisms if there's more than one $\mathbb Z/4$, more than two $\mathbb Z/2$'s, or one of each.  So the only such groups are those with at most four elements.

Answer (score 6):

No.  In fact, it is even possible for two finite groups $G$ and $H$ to have the same number of elements of each order, but still not be isomorphic.  I believe the smallest example of this is $G = \mathbb Z/4 \times \mathbb Z/4$ and $H = \mathbb Z/2 \times Q_8$, where $Q_8$ is the quaternion group.  Each of these has one identity, three elements of order 2, and twelve elements of order 4.  So there exist order-preserving bijections between them, but none of them is an isomorphism, as $G$ is abelian and $H$ is not.

Comment: I like this answer for actually giving a non-trivial example of two non-isomorphic groups between which an order-preserving bijection nonetheless exists.

Answer (score 3):

Considering $G$ to be any non-abelian group, the map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is a bijection, preserving orders of elements, which is not an isomorphism (since .....?......).