# Relation between the order of the elements of 2 groups and isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Let be $G$ and $H$ two equinumerous groups of order $n$.
We label the elements in such a way that 
$$
1< |g_1|\le|g_2|\le \cdots \le |g_n|
$$
$$
1< |h_1|\le|h_2|\le \cdots \le |h_n|
$$
If $(|g_1|,|g_2|,\cdots,|g_n|)\ne (|h_1|,|h_2|,\cdots,|h_n|)$ then $G\not\cong H$.

> Is there a result deducing from $(|g_1|,|g_2|,\cdots,|g_n|)= (|h_1|,|h_2|,\cdots,|h_n|)$ something about the isomorphism of $G$ and $H$?

Comment: Well one obvious property is that the isomorphism will send equal order elements to equal order elements and thus if $(|g_1|,...,|g_n|)$ is strictly increasing then the isomorphism is unique

Answer (score 1):

It does not follow that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic from the given hypothesis. As indicated in this answer to a similar question (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1478993/81163), $G = \mathbb{Z}/4\times \mathbb{Z}/4$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}/2 \times Q_8$. where $Q_8$ is the quaternions, are not isomorphic, but they have the same number of elements of each order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was clear to me, because of that I  I wrote "deduce something". Perhaps together with additional condition. Or one can restrict the collection of isomorphic classes, or deduce the number thereof. I don't know exactly, any result from which one can deduce something.